# How do fast food chains get away with selling fake chicken?

Tags: united-states, canada, fraud, food, fda

[Subway chicken only about 50% meat, according to Canadian study](https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/nation-now/2017/03/01/subway-chicken-only-50-meat-according-canadian-study/98582250/)

[image]

[What's in your chicken sandwich?](https://www.cbc.ca/news/business/marketplace-chicken-fast-food-1.3993967)

(Subway's "chicken" is 50% chicken, and Wendy's is 88%. The rest is non-meat additives)

Subway claimed that their chicken was

> "100% white meat with seasonings, marinated and delivered to our stores
>   as a finished, cooked product"

You'd think that they'd be prosecuted for fraud and other offenses, or at the very least sued.

How can they get away with it? Is this strictly a Canadian thing, or is this likely to happen in the US as well?

**EDIT** For those of you who've never been to Subway, you don't order a "chicken sandwich" there, you specify the ingredients, *e.g.* "chicken".

**EDIT** 
[According to lab tests done by CBC, if you buy fish at a grocery store in Canada, there is a good chance that your fish will be mislabeled (wrong species or origin). The food expert in the video stated that this is caused by poor legislation that doesn't punish this kind of mislabeling.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLmVCgoakDE)

Comment: "Meat" patties are only about half meat. That doesn't make them "fake meat" patties. This is a nonsensical question that ignores the facts to make unsubstantiated claims appealing to emotion.

Comment: @Nij Read TFA: "“Our chicken is 100% white meat with seasonings, marinated and delivered to our stores as a finished, cooked product," -- their official statement, but thanks for your "input" and downvotes.

Comment: 50% "seasoning", while misleading, wouldn't technically violate their claim as written.

Comment: You've said absolutely nothing that supports your position, then. 100% of the meat is meat. 50% of the finished product is the seasonings and marinade. These statements are not at all contradictory.

Comment: [Taco Bell was sued over the "meat" which is just 35% beef](https://www.foxnews.com/health/taco-bell-sued-over-meat-thats-just-35-percent-beef). The suit was later dropped when it was proved that it was actually 88% beef.

Comment: Don't take news titles as facts. Did you read the first article you cited? The rest of that article literally says their science wasn't peer reviewed and other researchers are unable to reproduce the results.

Answer (score 0):

### Chicken soup isn’t 100% chicken either

AFAIK subway sells you a chicken sandwich i.e. a sandwich containing *some* chicken. Where is the misrepresentation?

Comment: Did you read the comments or the linked article? Subway advertized their chicken as 100% chicken and stated **"Our chicken is 100% white meat with seasonings, marinated and delivered to our stores as a finished, cooked product,**

Comment: @MaxB Its misleading, but not necessarily incorrect. It is *100% white meat chicken* meaning all the chicken that is in it is white meat. If they were talking about the entire thing, they would say it is 99% chicken and 1% seasonings or something.